# Objective-C: atomic property is fully retrieved

Tags: objective-c, concurrency, thread-safety, atomic

With regards to atomic property, Apple's documentation has this below:

> This means that the synthesized accessors ensure that a value is
>   always fully retrieved by the getter method or fully set via the
>   setter method, even if the accessors are called simultaneously from
>   different threads.

What does "fully retrieved" or "fully set" mean?
Why is "fully retrieved" or "fully set" not enough to guarantee thread safety?

Note: I am aware there are many posts regarding atomicity on SO, please don't tag this as duplicate unless the ticket specifically address the question above.  After reading the posts, I still do not fully understand atomic property.

Answer (score 2):

Atomic means that calls to the getter/setter are synchronized. That way if one thread is setting the property at the same time as another thread is getting it, the one getting the property is guaranteed to get a valid return value. Without it being atomic, it would be possible that the getter retrieves a garbage value, or a pointer to an object that is immediately deallocated. When it's atomic, it will also ensure that if two threads try to set it at the same time, one will wait for the other to finish. If it weren't atomic and two threads tried to set it at the same time, you could end up with a garbage value being written, or possibly objects being over/under retained or over/under released.

So basically, if the property is being set, any other calls to set it or get it will wait for the method to return. Same for if the property is being gotten, any other calls to get it or set it will wait until that get finishes.

This is sometimes sufficient for thread safety depending on what it's being used for. But often you want more than this level of synchronization for thread safety. For example if one block of code on a thread gets the value, makes some change to it, and wants to set it again without some other thread changing it in the meantime. You would have to do additional synchronization to make sure that you have a lock on it from before you get it until after you subsequently set it. You would want to do the same if you wanted to get an object and make some changes to that object without another thread trying to make changes at the same time on it.

Answer (score 1):

"Fully set" and "fully retrieved" means the code below will always print "0x11111111" or "0x22222222". It will never print things like "0x11112222" or "0x11221122". Without `atomic` or some other appropriate thread synchronization, those sorts of partial reads or partial updates are allowed for some data types on some CPU architectures.

```
// Thread 1
while (true) x = 0x11111111;

// Thread 2
while (true) x = 0x22222222;

// Thread 3
while (true) printf("0x%x\n", x);
```

Comment: +1 Though in practice it would be extraordinarily unusual to see this behavior for pointers on 64-bit iPhone hardware.

Comment: Misaligned pointers that cross cache line boundaries are almost certainly vulnerable, though that shouldn't happen unless you're playing struct packing tricks.

Comment: Yep, not something that's going to happen in a vanilla iOS app.

Comment: Vanilla iOS apps are more likely to have trouble with `double`, which on 32-bit devices is also vulnerable.

Answer (score 0):

It means the value will never be accessed when it's halfway through being written. It will always be one intended value or another, never an incompletely altered bit pattern.

It isn't enough to guarantee thread-safety because ensuring that the value of a variable is either fully written or nor written at all is not enough to make all the code that uses that variable thread-safe. For example, there might be two variables that need to be updated together (the classical example is transferring credits from one account to another), but code in another thread could see one variable with the new value and one with the old.

Very often, you'll need to implement synchronization for whole systems, so the guarantees offered by atomic variables end up almost not mattering a lot of the time.

Comment: "The value will never accessed..." means never written or both written and read while it's being written?